# Remove foreign nuget packages from private nuget feed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-artifacts

When I look at my Artifacts feed I see hundreds of nuget packages from Microsoft and other authors who's packages I use.  Why are those packages stored in my feed?  Looking at the billing page I see that my feed uses 1.96 GB.  That is just below the 2 GB threshold after which I will be billed.  Of the 1.96 GB in use, maybe 10 mb is actually used by packages I create.

How do I remove the foreign nuget packages and prevent them from being stored in my feed?

Comment: If you go to DevOps > Artifacts > Settings, do you have any upstream sources defined?

Comment: Yes, nuget.org, npmjs.

Comment: Those will be causing it. You could remove them; they have advantages (sometimes) but most likely you don't need them.

Comment: Thank you.  Please put your comments in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check (and remove if desired) Artifacts > Settings > [Upstream Sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops).

In most cases there is no need to use these, but there can be some [benefits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#benefits-of-upstream-sources), the main one being that if an upstream version (or entire package) is removed, your package will still have access to the copy that Azure will have made for you.